# Can you use .valueOf () to build better ifString function?

Tags: javascript, string

Simplest fool proof(?) method to check for string object I've seen. Tested with many different objects types. Are there parameters/circumstances that might trip it up, and are there simper functions available?

```
function isString(o){
    if(o == null || o == undefined){
        return false;
    }
    if(typeof(o) == 'string'){
        return true;
    }
    if(typeof(o) == 'object'&& typeof(o.valueOf) == 'function' && typeof(o.valueOf()) == 'string'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's what I've check with:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="el">
<script type="text/javascript">

function isString(o){
    if(o == null || o == undefined){
        return false;
    }
    if(typeof(o) == 'string'){
        return true;
    }
    if(typeof(o) == 'object'&& typeof(o.valueOf) == 'function' && typeof(o.valueOf()) == 'string'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
function tellIfString(o){
    if(isString(o)){
        return "A string!<br />";
    }else{
        return "Not a string!<br />";
    }
}
function CustomO(a){
    this.a = a;
}
literal = 'string';
objectWrapped = new String('why do i feel different?');
stringNumber = '345';
number = 234;
numberWrapped = new Number(3345);
object = {};
array = [];
bool = true;
nan = 1*'sdf';
regex = /woop/;
regex_o = new RegExp('asasd');
o_no_valueOf = {};
o_no_valueOf = delete(o_no_valueOf.valueOf);
customO = new CustomO({});
document.write("literal Is "+tellIfString(literal));
document.write("objectWrapped string Is "+tellIfString(objectWrapped));
document.write("stringNumber Is "+tellIfString(stringNumber));
document.write("number Is "+tellIfString(number));
document.write("numberWrapped Is "+tellIfString(numberWrapped));
document.write("object Is "+tellIfString(object));
document.write("array Is "+tellIfString(array));
document.write("bool Is "+tellIfString(bool));
document.write("nan Is "+tellIfString(nan));
document.write("null Is "+tellIfString(null));
//document.write("notdefined Is "+tellIfString(notdefined));//don't need to check variables that haven't been defined, they error before they get to the function
document.write("undefined Is "+tellIfString(undefined));
document.write("Math Is "+tellIfString(Math));
document.write("function Is "+tellIfString(function(){}));
document.write("regex Is "+tellIfString(regex));
document.write("regexO Is "+tellIfString(regex_o));
document.write("o_no_valueOf Is "+tellIfString(regex_o));
document.write("customO Is "+tellIfString(customO));
document.write("jQuery return Is "+tellIfString($('#el')));
document.write("document Is "+tellIfString(document));//this case is important because it requires the typeof(o.valueOf) == 'function'
document.write("window Is "+tellIfString(window));
document.write("document.cookie Is "+tellIfString(document.cookie));
document.write("window.open Is "+tellIfString(window.open));
document.write("window.location Is "+tellIfString(window.location));
document.write("All objects evaluated!");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See also(especially the parts about `new String` and `.valueOf()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: What's your question? This is not a blog. However, this function will incorrectly classify `{valueOf: function() {return 'foo';} }` as string. Better might be: `if(({}).toString.call(o) === '[object String]')`

Comment: Is there a question here, or did you just want to post a function you made?

Comment: I would recommend reworking this into a question with an answer. We encourage information sharing provided you comply with the guidelines: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking  also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: -"Will this sweet function I made work in the Wild, and are there better alternatives"

Comment: Or perhaps if you're looking for a review of your code I could migrate your question to our Code Review site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's more sensible to write:

```
function isString(o)
    { return typeof(o) == 'string' || o instanceof String; }
```

**Edited to add:** This is not absolutely foolproof; Felix Kling, in the comments, points out one case where it will not work. Based on [this page](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/), I believe that this:

```
function isString(o)
    { return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object String]'; }
```

is "more" foolproof. (I've found that you can still break it by messing with `Object.prototype.toString`, and perhaps in other ways, but if you distrust your own code that much, then there's really nothing you can do.)

Comment: Will probably work most of the time, though there are edge cases where this can fail, e.g. if you retrieve a `String` object from an iframe.

Comment: @FelixKling: Fair enough. I've updated my answer.